# Can't connect to SQL from Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

I tried to query my syslogins with this script in powershell. It gives me this error:
"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not 
found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

The error shown:

> provider: Named Pipes Provider,  error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server

Remote Access is enabled on the Database I try to connect to.
This is the code im working with:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$conn.ConnectionString = "server=servername.hsr.ch;database=mydb;Integrated Security=true;"
$conn.open()
$cmd.Connection = $conn
$cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM syslogins" 
$out = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$conn.close()
print $out
```

Comment: Are you positive that the user that's running the PowerShell has the permission to access the DB? Did you check that the server name is correct? Did you check your SQL server log whenever it has some more information?

Comment: Does your DB instance enabled IP / Name Pipe access? Check the instance in SQL Server Configuration

Comment: Firewall could also be an issue.

Comment: After checking what other above said, I would check if you can connect via SQL Client first, then you can try to connect via telnet to that port, third does your integrated security work correctly?

Comment: Yes, the integrated security works correctly. It is also possible to connect via SQL client.